# Nginx PHP-FPM Health Check

Tags: php, nginx

I want to write a health check that takes Nginx and PHP-FPM into account. Currently my health check works as such:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    location /nginx-health {
        access_log off;
        return 200 "healthy\n";
    }

}
```

The problem is sometimes nginx will be totally healthy, but the connection to the upstream, php-fpm, is not working. In which this health check will errousenly return healthy. How can a health  also check php-fpm?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a server directive that will utilize a php-fpm location with a simple php file, which if parsed correctly will return the same 200 reply.

Additional checks can also be put in the PHP check location/file.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: I do, but why not see your efforts (and the errors you experienced), before receiving a ready solution? :)